# Getting parameters values blank and null when using custom wsdl in axis2

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

I am using axis2 for my web services creation. I want to use my own wsdl file instead of using generated wsdl file. When I am placing my own wsdl file in META-INF directory and deploying my web services they are deploying successfully.  But the problem is when i try to test these web service using soapui it throwing null pointer exception.

For example I am invoking following operations in soap ui.

```
 public String testWebService(String a, String b)
 {
      LogHelper.info("Value of a is:"+a);
      LogHelper.info("Value of b is :"+b);
      String c=a.trim()+b.Trim();
      return "suceess"
 }

 output in console:

 value of a is:
 value of b is:null
 19:58:47,781 ERROR [RPCMessageReceiver] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method testWebService
```

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:173)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:142)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at o......................................................

SO What i understand is i am getting value for a is blank and value of b is null.

Can any one give me any suggestions please.

Thanks,

Narendra

Comment: what r the values you are sending from soapUI?

Comment: I am send values Strings. like in soap request I am sending "string1" , "String2"